# Lex - Do the rules only match to the tokens or over the sequence of tokens?

Tags: lex

In Lex, there are a set of rules defined. Do the rules only apply to the tokens that are delimitated by spaces and such? If there is any block in the line buffer that matches the rule, will it work?

For example, if I want to write a rule that checks the function of a program (e.g., void sum()) with a rule such as "void "[a-zA-Z]+"()", this rule should be matched to a line. Can rules that span over more than a single token work in Lex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `yylex`, it finds the longest match *starting at the current buffer pointer*. It does not search for a token. It will match spaces if (and only if) the rule can match space characters.

Lex has no idea of what a `token` is other than "a sequence of characters which match a rule", so the question about whether a rule can span more than a token is meaningless. By definition, anything which matches a rule is a token.

There must always be some rule which matches, since the scanner will never match anything which doesn't start at the current buffer pointer. By default, lex adds a rule (if necessary) at the end which matches any character and echoes it to `yyout`. Unless you're writing a transducer, that is almost certainly not what you want, so I always recommend that you add

```
%option nodefault
```

(assuming you are actually using `flex`, which is by far the most common lex implementation); that will suppress the default rule and give you a warning if it is possible that no rule matches the input. Then you can define your own fallback rule, which might be something like:

```
.|\n    { return yytext[0]; }
```

or which might throw a scanner error.